# REST: convert XML content passed with POST to a java object, attribute inside the element

Tags: java, rest, jersey, xmlmapper

I am working with REST services and i want to pass an XML-text with a POST request. My server is implemented in JAVA. Let's say that i am sending this XML:

```
<range>
  <higher value="3"></higher>
  <lower value="2"></lower>
</range>
```

---

As i understand (correct me if i am wrong), the easiest way to convert the XML in the request to a java object, is to define a class with the proper annotations. For example:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "range")
public class RangeClass {

    @XmlElement (name = "lower")
    private int lower;

    @XmlElement (name = "higher")
    private int higher;

    .
    .
    ???
}
```

---

And then read it like this:

```
@POST
@PATH(<somePath>)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String myFun(RangeClass range) {
  .
  .
  .
}
```

---

The thing that i am missing (if the other parts are correct) is how to define that i have attributes inside the elements. If i put an '@XmlAttribute' annotation this will refer to an attribute of the root element ('range') and not an attribute of a specific element ('lower' or 'higher').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First** and the easiest way is to create a Java mapping per each XML tag:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "range")
public class RangeClass {

    private Higher higher;

    private Lower lower;
}

@XmlElement(name = "higher")
public class Higher {

    @XmlAttribute
    private int value;
}

@XmlElement(name = "lower")
public class Lower {

    @XmlAttribute
    private int value;
}
```

**Second** option is to change XML structure to:

```
<range>
  <higher>3</higher>
  <lower>2</lower>
</range>
```

Then you can use **@XmlElement** annotation:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "range")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) 
public class RangeClass {

    @XmlElement
    private int lower;

    @XmlElement
    private int higher;

}
```

**Third** option is to use [Eclipse Link Moxy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) and its @XmlPath annotation:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "range")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) 
public class RangeClass {

    @XmlPath("lower/@value")
    private int lower;

    @XmlPath("higher/@value")
    private int higher;

}
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is what i wanted. I used the second option but i replaced the 'XmlValue' anotation with 'XmlElement' because i was having this error: '1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions XmlValue is only allowed one per class, but two properties are annotated with XmlValue'.

Comment: Also i have added setters and getters and when i tried to run my program i got this error: '1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "lower"'. The same goes for "higher". The error was gone when i removed the SETTERS. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Sorry for not checking the answer in IDE), I have updated the second option. You can try @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) to avoid error with setters