# how to add attributes inside XML element in REST

Tags: java, xml, rest, annotations

I am doing **`Rest`** webservice in java. I need to pass an **`XML`** with post request. My XML is as follows:

```
<Case><Version>1.0</Version><Code>457123</Code><Id>TRD</Id><Meta uc=\"Sample\" pip=\"116.0.1.1\" lot=\"P\"/><Case>
```

I am converting this XML to java object by defining a class with proper annotations.

But how to add attributes for `XMLElement <Meta>`. If i add `@XmlAttribute` then the attributes are added for the root xml element

Pls suggest a way to do the same. I am using Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/TESTINGrestful/rest/polls/comment");
StringEntity input = new StringEntity("<Comment>...</Comment>");
input.setContentType("text/xml");
postRequest.setEntity(input);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

Try experimenting with this. Its something taken from this
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/PostXML.java?view=markup

**Update**
If you are looking for mapping your XML to Java then try this

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Case")
public class CaseClass {
    @XmlElement
    private int Version;

    @XmlElement
    private int Code;

    @XmlElement
    private int Id;

    private meta Meta;
}

@XmlElement(name = "Meta")
public class meta {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String uc;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String pip;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String lot;
}
```

Comment: am not doing client..am doing the webservice

Comment: The answer has been update to include the mapping for XML if you are looking for that.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Meta")
public class Meta{

private UC uc;

}

@XmlElement(name = "uc")
public class UC{

@XmlAttribute
private String value;
}
```

follow this link for more useful alternatives
[REST: convert XML content passed with POST to a java object, attribute inside the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719036/rest-convert-xml-content-passed-with-post-to-a-java-object-attribute-inside-th?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for ur kind reply @khurram .. I will check it out and come

Comment: But my rootelemt is Case and not Meta.. Meta is an element

Comment: yes you should have a reference from Case Class of Meta object and it should work